# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'on_delete'

Tags: django, django-models

I built a model:

```
class Channel(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(allow_unicode=True, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, default='')
    description_html = models.TextField(editable=False, default='', 
blank=True)
    subscribers = models.ManyToManyField(User, 
through="ChannelMembers", on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
```

When I do makemigration it say :

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'on_delete'
```

And when a delete the **on_delete** it say:

```
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'on_delete'
```

What's worng?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`on_delete` is not a valid argument on a `ManyToManyField`. You would need to use the `on_delete` argument in each of the `ForeignKey` fields in the `through` model for `ChannelMembers` instead.

You can see the following example how this is achievable on the [Django Docs website](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through_fields)

In your case it would look something like this:

```
class Channel(models.Model):
    ...
    # Don't have the on_delete parameter on this field
    subscribers = models.ManyToManyField(User, through="ChannelMembers")

# Add on_delete to both the fields in this class instead
class ChannelMembers(models.Model):
    channel = models.ForeignKey(Channel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subscriber = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```